# SSL warning page includes other resources which are not secure

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I have two web pages that sits on identical servers

1. https://cupstelaviv.com/index.html
2. https://app.cupsapp.com/index.html

They both sit on identical servers (different SSL certificate)

The second one gives me SSL warning

> Your connection to app.cupsapp.com is encrypted with 256-bit encryption. However, this page includes other resources which are not secure. These resources can be viewed by others while in transit, and can be modified by an attacker to change the behavior of the page.
>
> The connection uses TLS 1.0.
>
> The connection is encrypted using AES_256_CBC, with SHA1 for message authentication and RSA as the key exchange mechanism.

What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error I see is different.

> This is not the site you are looking for

[image]

This error happens when you are using a certificate generated for another hostname. In this case, it looks like the certificate you are using for `app.cupsapp.com` was generated for `cupstelaviv.com`.

In order to avoid the warning, you need to purchase and install a certificate for the hostname `app.cupsapp.com`.

Comment: Oh, there's a complication that I did'nt add to the question - i'm using AWS Route 53 with LBR so in case you are in europe, you will see this message, in the US you will see my message. sorry about that. I fixed it now (removed the LBR), now you should see the message I mentioned

Comment: Nope, I keep seeing the host name mismatch error.

Comment: how about now ?

Comment: Now it works, but it works in all the senses. I don't see any error message. http://cl.ly/image/3b0u1x3Q1i1c

Comment: you're right, somehow it fixed itself now. very weird. I have one old tab opened with the warning and now a new tab without. might be chrome cache issues. thanks !

Answer (score 3):

The ERROR - "However, this page includes other resources which are not secure. These resources can be viewed by others while in transit, and can be modified by an attacker to change the behavior of the page."
This error pops up because there are items or links on your page which are coming from http instead of https. Please see the source of web page, you will find the links with plain http.